# Convert Java code to Delphi about midpoint calculation

Tags: java, delphi

I found this Java code to calculate the midpoint between two latitude and longitude:
[midpoint between two latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656802/midpoint-between-two-latitude-and-longitude)

```
public static void midPoint(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2){

    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

    //convert to radians
    lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    lon1 = Math.toRadians(lon1);

    double Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
    double By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
    double lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By));
    double lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);

    //print out in degrees
    System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(lat3) + " " + Math.toDegrees(lon3));
}
```

Anyone can help me to convert this piece of code to Borland Delphi?

With the input like this format:

lat1 = 48.865223,
lon1 = 2.318974

lat2 = 48.865983,
lon2 = 2.321475

I am not sure if that is already in "radian".

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Lx3Rm6fV

Comment: Math.ToRadians is DegToRad. The rest of code is very simple.

Comment: @TLama - post it as an answer, I will delete mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
lat1 = 48.865223, lon1 = 2.318974
lat2 = 48.865983, lon2 = 2.321475
```

These coordinates appear to be in degrees. The latitude is too large for radians. You can convert between degrees and radians using `DegToRad` and `RadToDeg`. Of course, it's not very hard to multiply and divide by π/180.

The trig functions, `sin` and `cos` can be found in the `System` unit, as can `sqrt`. For `atan2` you need `arctan2` from `Math`.