# Intelligently suggesting a meeting place close to two people on a map

Tags: android, geolocation

Hie Guys,

I am thinking of creating an android application that is able to suggest the nearest meeting place for two people. These people must be located on a map. Is there any way i can bring the issue of "intelligence" within the suggestion of the meeting place to make the application more cooler?

I have so far noted that i can make suggestions based on all the meeting places within the circle created around the diameter of the circle (distance between point A and point B). Other factors that may come into play are the meeting place bookings based on their inventory system.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this method to get the midpoint between two latitudes/longitudes :
[midpoint between two latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656802/midpoint-between-two-latitude-and-longitude)

And use google places api https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/
to get a place around that midpoint (like a bar or restaurant...)