# Google Maps between two Points A and B. But, both of the points will be set automatically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to use a map where both source and destination address will be pre-filled.

Like, I would prompt user to select current location, i.e, point A. ( I  already did that) . Then, I will list up some places based on his/her location. Now, I want to take that address directly to the Destination Address  , i.e, point B. and ,I will show to the user the route and exact Distance. Can You tell me how to prefix the Address for Point B, as I said above?

But, Both of the locations would be changed any time.
for example,

My current location is BTM Layout, Bangalore , India (Source)and The Restaurant I want to go is in Koramangala, Bangalore, India(Destination). 
Later I changed my mind and want to go to another restaurant which is in Marathahalli, Bangalore, India(Destination). Let, In this case my source address also changed , its now HSR Layout, Bangalore, India.

My app will draw a map between this two location.
Can anyone please help me out ? How to do it? Is it possible to get direction like this?

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is about the zoom, you can try something like this :

1. Create to Location objets from your two points (assuming they are both in LatLng objets)

   ```
   // Start position
   Location locStart = new Location("");
   locStart.setLatitude(lngStart.latitude);
   locStart.setLongitude(lngStart.longitude);

   // End position
   Location locEnd = new Location("");
   locEnd.setLatitude(lngEnd.latitude);
   locEnd.setLongitude(lngEnd.longitude);
   ```
2. Get the distance between your two points

   ```
   double distance = locStart.distanceTo(locEnd);
   ```
3. Get the right zoom level

   The Maps API uses zoom levels (0 = far away ... 20 = buildings), so you have to found a way to switch between a distance (in meters) and a zoom level.

   ```
   int level;

   if (distance < 500) level = 1;
   else if (distance >= 500 && distance < 2000) level = 2;
   // and continue ...
   ```

   (values are for only the example, not tested)
4. Get the virtual midpoint

   (so you can center your map)

   Check that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656937/5200029), I'm not good in maths :)
5. Update map

   ```
   map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(midpoint, level));
   ```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you explain the first point a little more. Actually, as I said my Source and Destination address is getting changed every time. Its easy to get the source( current location) , but how to add destination address automatically the map?