# solve two simultaneous equations: one contains a Python function

Tags: python, sympy

On the below map, I have two known points (**A and B**) with their coordinates (**longitude, latitude**). I need to derive the coordinates of a point **C** which is on the line, and is 100 kilometres away from **A**.
[image]

First I created a function to calculate the distances between two points in kilometres:

```
# pip install haversine
from haversine import haversine

def get_distance(lat_from,long_from,lat_to,long_to):
    distance_in_km = haversine((lat_from,long_from),
                               (lat_to, long_to),
                                unit='km')

    return distance_in_km
```

Then using the slope and the distance, the coordinates of point **C** should be the solution to the below equations:

```
# line segment AB and AC share the same slope, so
# (15.6-27.3)/(41.6-34.7) = (y-27.3)/(x-34.7)

# the distance between A and C is 100 km, so
# get_distance(y,x,27.3,34.7) = 100
```

Then I try to solve these two equations in Python:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

slope = (15.6-27.3)/(41.6-34.7)
x, y = symbols('x y')
eq1 = Eq(y-slope*(x-34.7)-27.3)
eq2 = Eq(get_distance(y,x,34.7,27.3)-100)
solve((eq1,eq2), (x, y))
```

The error is `TypeError: can't convert expression to float`. I may understand the error, because the `get_distance` function is expecting inputs as floats, while my `x` and `y` in `eq2` are `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol`.

I tried to add `np.float(x)`, but the same error remains.

Is there a way to solve equations like these? Or do you have better ways to achieve what is needed?

Many thanks!

```
# there is a simple example of solving equations:
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
x, y = symbols('x y')
eq1 = Eq(2*x-y)
eq2 = Eq(x+2-y)
solve((eq1,eq2), (x, y))

# output: {x: 2, y: 4}
```

Comment: I'm not surprised.  I don't know anything about `havesine`, but assuming it uses some sort trig calculations, it either uses `math.sin` or `np.sin`.  `math.sin(x)` produces this error.  It would be interesting to see the full traceback, but I don't think it will help.  `scipy` has some numerical solvers that might work better.

Comment: does the data type `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol` contain some sort of field/attribute from which you can fetch float values?

Comment: If you want a symbolic solution, you need to rewrite your function to only use authentic sympy functions.  See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points) for a formula, where you should change all `sin`, `cos`, `asin`, `sqrt` and conversion to radians to their sympy equivallent.

Comment: This can be calculated and doesn't need to be solved with solver. That is, if there is a solution. If both points are less than 100KM away from each other, there is no solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767074/intermediate-points-between-2-geographic-coordinates?rq=1 is related. Let me know if you want a python example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly calculate that point. We can [implement a python version of the intermediate calculation for lat long](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Be aware this calculations assume the earth is a sphere, and takes the curve into account, i.e. this is not a Euclidean approximation like your original post.

Say we have two (lat,long) points `A` and `B`;

```
import numpy as np

A = (52.234869, 4.961132)
B = (46.491267, 26.994655)

EARTH_RADIUS = 6371.009
```

We can than calculate the intermediate point fraction `f` by taking 100/`distance-between-a-b-in-km`

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')

point_1 = np.array([A])
point_2 = np.array([B])

delta = dist.pairwise(np.radians(point_1), np.radians(point_2) )[0][0] 

f = 100 / (delta * EARTH_RADIUS)

phi_1, lambda_1 = np.radians(point_1)[0]
phi_2, lambda_2 = np.radians(point_2)[0]

a = np.sin((1-f) * delta) / np.sin(delta)
b = np.sin( f * delta) / np.sin(delta)

x = a * np.cos(phi_1) * np.cos(lambda_1) + b * np.cos(phi_2) * np.cos(lambda_2)
y = a * np.cos(phi_1) * np.sin(lambda_1) + b * np.cos(phi_2) * np.sin(lambda_2)

z = a * np.sin(phi_1) + b * np.sin(phi_2)
phi_n = np.arctan2(z, np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) )
lambda_n = np.arctan2(y,x)
```

The point C, going from A to B, with 100 km distance from A, is than

```
C = np.degrees( phi_n ), np.degrees(lambda_n)
```

In this case

```
(52.02172458025681, 6.384361456573444)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am still thinking about your answer, and trying your codes with my real research data, I will approve it as soon as I can.

Comment: Initially I had concerns with precisions due to assumptions made in this solution or any other ones, like the fixed value of earth radius. But then I think these are inevitable. And there are already large uncertainties in my research data (i.e. the satellite retrievals). So for now, I decide to carry on. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: thx and happy it (somewhat) works. There are indeed precision errors, good to read https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#ellipsoid on this. This also mentioned the Vincenty alternative. It is more involved but more precise. I am not aware of a (elegant) form to get intermediate point for vincenty