# Get mid point between 4 LonLat Android

Tags: android, location, average

I have 4 LonLat points and i would like to find the midpoint of the 4.
To do so I took the first 2 found the mid point, then the second 2 found the point, then find the midpoint between the 2 first results.

To find the mid point between my points i used the code found on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656937/4489629

Unforuntaly it does not work i get a value that is on the equator for some reason, while the locations that I am trying to find the midpoint are in the UK.

Here is my code:

```
private void treatForDispaly(double averageSpeed, double averageElevation, RecordObject[] records) {
        String currentDateTimeString = String.valueOf(new java.util.Date());

        LatLng firstTwo = midPoint(records[0].getLatitude(), records[0].getLongitude(), records[1].getLatitude(), records[1].getLongitude());
//        LatLng seconTwo = midPoint(records[2].getLatitude(), records[2].getLongitude(), records[3].getLatitude(), records[3].getLongitude());
//        LatLng averageLatLng = midPoint(firstTwo.latitude, firstTwo.longitude, seconTwo.latitude, seconTwo.longitude);

        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(ContentProviderContract.DAILY_RECORDS_TREATED_DATETIME,currentDateTimeString);
        newValues.put(ContentProviderContract.DAILY_RECORDS_TREATED_ALTITUDE, averageElevation);
        newValues.put(ContentProviderContract.DAILY_RECORDS_TREATED_SPEED, averageSpeed);
        newValues.put(ContentProviderContract.DAILY_RECORDS_TREATED_LATITUDE, records[0].getLatitude()); // firstTwo.latitude
        newValues.put(ContentProviderContract.DAILY_RECORDS_TREATED_LONGITUDE, records[0].getLongitude()); //firstTwo.longitude

        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(ContentProviderContract.DAILY_RECORDS_TREATED_URI, newValues);

        RecordTreatedObject tempRecord = new RecordTreatedObject();
        tempRecord.setDateTime(new Date(currentDateTimeString));
        tempRecord.setElevation(averageElevation);
        tempRecord.setLatitude(firstTwo.latitude);
        tempRecord.setLongitude(firstTwo.longitude);
        tempRecord.setSpeed(averageSpeed);
        dailyRecordsTreated.add(tempRecord);
    }

    public static LatLng midPoint(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2){
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

        lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        lon1 = Math.toRadians(lon1);

        double Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
        double By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
        double lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By));
        double lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);

        //return out in degrees
        LatLng midpoint = new LatLng(lat3, lon3);
        return  midpoint;
    }
```

Here are the values that I am inputing:

```
D/DEBUG: first locatoin lat: 52.954037691647834 long: 52.954037691647834
D/DEBUG: second locatoin lat: 52.95385240191483 long: 52.95385240191483
```

and here is what i get as a result:

```
D/DEBUG: midpoint lat 0.9242206929866051 midpoint long: 0.9242206929866051
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a wild guess but it seems to be that you are getting results in radians. Convert result back to degrees and you get 52.9539448 which is correct I presume.