# How to get the list of coordinates (Lat, Long) of a poly-line drawn between drawn between two markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, google-polyline

Actually i need a list of coordinates on which the line is drawn mention in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOdAH.jpg) in details

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When drawing a `PloyLine` save it in a global variable , If there are multiple `PolyLines` save them in a list . Use method `polyline.getPoints()` on `PolyLine` variable it will give you the `List<LatLng>`

**Edit:**  If you want multiple points just find the center point between two points check [midpoint between two latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656802/midpoint-between-two-latitude-and-longitude)

Comment: polyline.getPoints() will only give us the lat,long of starting and ending of the polyline where markers are placed

Comment: what else do you want ?

Comment: If you want more points on line just keep calculating center points between two latlng

Comment: i need a Coordinates (lat, long) of intermediate points between two markers on the polyline

Comment: is there any function to calculate the center point or i have to do it manually?

Comment: yeah i just implemented it in my code hope for the best results

Comment: which code? , there are more solutions over there you can try different one